# How to convert string arraylist to model arraylist in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, arraylist

```
List<String> langList = [English,  Gujarati,  Hindi,  Marathi,  Punjabi,  Urdu,  Spanish]

var selectedLanguagesList = <LanguageDatum>[].obs;
```

langList is a string type of list. and selectedLanguagesList is a model type of list.
How do I convert string list to model list in flutter ?

```
class LanguageDatum {
  LanguageDatum({
     this.id,
     this.name,
     this.status,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.deletedAt,
  });

  int? id;
  String? name;
  int? status;
  DateTime? createdAt;
  DateTime? updatedAt;
  dynamic deletedAt;

  factory LanguageDatum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LanguageDatum(
    id: json["id"]??0,
    name: json["name"]??"",
    status: json["status"]??"",
    createdAt: json["created_at"] != null ? DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]) : null,
    updatedAt: json["updated_at"] != null ? DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]) : null,
    deletedAt: json["deleted_at"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "status": status,
    "created_at": createdAt,
    "updated_at": updatedAt,
    "deleted_at": deletedAt,
  };
}
```

So, Above is model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I guess it would be

```
// To convert String array to Model array
final listOfLanguageDatum =
    langList.map((e) => LanguageDatum(name: e)).toList();

List<String> langList = [
  'Tamil'
  'English',
  'Gujarati',
  'Hindi',
  'Marathi',
  'Punjabi',
  'Urdu',
  'Spanish'
];

class LanguageDatum extends GetxController {
  LanguageDatum({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.status,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.deletedAt,
  });

  int? id;
  String? name;
  int? status;
  DateTime? createdAt;
  DateTime? updatedAt;
  dynamic deletedAt;

  factory LanguageDatum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LanguageDatum(
        id: json["id"] ?? 0,
        name: json["name"] ?? "",
        status: json["status"] ?? "",
        createdAt: json["created_at"] != null
            ? DateTime.parse(json["created_at"])
            : null,
        updatedAt: json["updated_at"] != null
            ? DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"])
            : null,
        deletedAt: json["deleted_at"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "status": status,
        "created_at": createdAt,
        "updated_at": updatedAt,
        "deleted_at": deletedAt,
      };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'LanguageDatum(id: $id, name: $name, status: $status, createdAt: $createdAt, updateAt: $updatedAt, deletedAt: $deletedAt)';
  }
}
```

Comment: electedLanguagesList  :::  [Instance of 'LanguageDatum', Instance of 'LanguageDatum']

Comment: I passed this,     selectedLanguagesList.value = split.map((e) => LanguageDatum(name: e.toString())).toList().obs;

Comment: I think you can assign e.name to the name variable?

Comment: e is itself string. so we can't pass e.name.toString();

Comment: emm, can I take a look at your Class?

Comment: I have updated my question. Plz go through that.

Comment: If you just want to check the object value by printing it, you have to override the toString method, otherwise only instance of 'LanguageDatum' will be shown. Updated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your language is of String type, to make language object You need to make a model class say,

```
Class LanguageDatum{
String name;
   ...
}
```